# Rails -- require administrator confirmation before sign-up?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've finished the Rails tutorial (http://ruby.railstutorial.org/) up until the microposts section, and I've been wondering -- I want to make it so that when users sign up, they are not added to the `users` table until an administrator confirms their signup; i.e. an email is sent to the administrator to notify them that someone has signed up. How do I implement this (seemingly) simple functionality? I've checked the Rails Screencasts, to no avail.

Thanks.

Comment: You can add an `accepted` flag on the `User` model then use an admin backend (like `activeadmin`) to set this flag. Then you can set something to send an email once this flag has been set. This is a relatively common task.

Comment: As @ITNinja mentioned, you need to add a "flag" column to the users table which needs to be activated to activate the account.  You aren't going to be able to "not add them to the users table" until the administrator confirms their signup because you still need to store their details somewhere.  Once the admin marks the flag column, you can send out an email stating the account is activated.  You will also need to add a before_filter checking that the user has been activated.

Comment: Thanks. Does anyone know of any tutorials regarding anything similar to this? I haven't been able to locate anything. Thanks.